# My method needs to increase the incomes by percentages

Tags: c#

Write a method ChangeSalaries. It changes the salary of all people. The method has two inputs: a list of 
incomes and a salary increase (as a percentage). It returns nothing. This method modifies the list. Note when

For example ChangeSalaries (incomes, 5) will increase all incomes by 5%.

This is what i have so far but it doesn't quite work, i know that i need the percent to appear like (* 0.15, or 0.20) etc to generate a percent but i can't work it out here

```
    public static void ChangeSalaries(List<double> incomez, int percent)

    for (int i = 0; i < incomez.Count; ++i)
    {
          Console.WriteLine(incomez[i] * percent);

    }

    }
```

Comment: Well, take 10%, i.e. 0.1 what happens if you multiple (say) 50 by 0.1? You get 5, not 55. So you *either* need to add that amount to `incomez`... or realize that an increase of 10% is a multiplier of 1.1, not 0.1...

Comment: What's the input, expected output, and actual output you're currently getting? _(Also, FWIW, might want to re-word this so it's not so obvious it's a homework question.)_

Comment: @GrantWinney: Homework itself isn't a problem, IMO - the OP has shown what they've tried, which is a very good start.

Comment: Well firstly your math should be `incomez[i] * (1 + percent/100)`, since that's what you actually want. I also need to ask: is your code sample the exact method you're putting in your application, or is it just a simplified example?

Comment: @GrantWinney: I've helped on that front just now by removing the shoutiness in the title :)

Comment: @Jason It is the exact method - I've tried implementing your way of doing into the code, but now its just printing the indexes with no change to the percentage :/

Comment: @Jason All good, i fixed the int paramater to a double

Answer (score 0):

First your calculation wrong. and change your method like this it will work.

```
 public static void ChangeSalaries(List<double> incomez, int percent)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < incomez.Count; ++i)
        {

          incomez[i] = ((incomez[i] * percent) / 100) + incomez[i];

          Console.WriteLine(incomez[i]);

        }

    }
```